# Modifying and Adding JSON Attributes

Tags: javascript, json, express, backend

I'm building a ecommerce website that has multiple image in a product for the user to see.

I made a two tables in the database `productdetails` containing sizes, price, etc. and `productimage` which stores a foreign key & pathname.

[This is what I retrieve from my backend (Expressjs)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkUA6.png)

I am trying to modify it to look like this but no luck.

> [{"id":2,
>
> "product_id":2,
>
> "image": {
>
> "pathname1": "images\shop\2.jpg",
>
> "pathname2": "images\shop\3.jpg", },
>
> "descrition": "..."
>
> }]

I'm also using this query for now.

`SELECT * FROM productimage a INNER JOIN productdetails b WHERE a.product_id=b.id AND b.id=${id}`

Comment: I am a bit confused. You use SQL query but labeled the question and output as JSON?

Comment: I'm developing an api for the backend using Express.js so I am using sql queries to retrieve the data I need for the visualization. The result is converted to json for the frontend to fetch. @NanoBit